DAX not adding hh:mm:ss time in Power BI
I have a data in the excel as :

I want to calculate the TAT/interval/day/PNR in power BI.
I wrote the following DAX:
Total Txns Considered for TAT = 
SUM('Time to Ticket'[PNR Count])

Time to Ticket = 
VAR TATinMins=
    SUMX(
        'Time to Ticket',
        HOUR('Time to Ticket'[TAT])*60 +
        MINUTE('Time to Ticket'[TAT])+
        SECOND('Time to Ticket'[TAT])/60
    )
RETURN
    IF(
        ISBLANK(
            DIVIDE(
                TATinMins,
                [Total Txns Considered for TAT],0)
        ),
        0,
            DIVIDE(
                TATinMins,
                [Total Txns Considered for TAT],0)
    )

This calculation is giving in correct output for all regions except EMEA.
I have revalidated the formatting. It is same for every region. There are no blanks in the data as well.
Where can I be possibly going wrong? Please help!

Can you share data for EMEA ?
